# Positionning Xfce terminal on desktop

Tags: command-line, xfce

At lauching Xfce terminal with Ubuntu Studio, it usually pops up in the middle of the screen but I want it to locate to the lowerleft corner.

1) Using the "Scrolling terminal" tab in xfce4-settings-manager, I set up these position parameters : leftmost and downmost on the linear scales.
As a result, when I launched a terminal it still poped up right in the middle of the screen.

2) In the .config/xfce4/terminal/terminalarc file, I replaced DropdownPositionVertical=100 with =20 but it didn't make it.

I searched thru many more webpages but it didn't help.

Comment: See something like:  https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=216264

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48984/how-can-i-set-the-position-that-terminal-opens-at

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu Studio do you use?

Answer (score 0):

It's not so difficult to find an answer to your question, I found it on the internet and used it for years now:

#width x height + offset from left side desktop window + offset from top desktop window (taking into account panels and menu bars)

#next setting says: open a terminal which is 200 characters wide and 62 characters  high (current font settings in terminal), upper left corner is at 260 pixels from left side desktop and 0 pixels from the top of my desktop (e.g. right under the taskbar which is at the top of my screen).

#You may have to experiment with the settings before it is to your likings.

MiscDefaultGeometry=200x62+260+0

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--geometry` this:

```
xfce4-terminal --geometry=70x20+200+400
```

In the above example:

- `70` is the width in columns
- `20` is the height rows
- `200` is the amount of pixels from the left side of the screen
- `400` is the amount of pixels from the top of the screen

Thus, the above example creates a terminal positioned bottom left on my 1080p screen.